Spectrum and Eigenvalues of the difference of projections
Let $P$ and $Q$ be two orthogonal projections on a Hilbert space, i.e. $P^2 = P^* = P$. I am interested in studying the spectrum and the eigenvalues of $P-Q$.
I know that $P-Q$ is self-adjoint and $\|P-Q\| \leq 1$, so $\sigma(P-Q) \subset [-1,1]$. However, intuitively I'd feel like the only possible values in the spectrum are the eigenvalues $-1,0,1$, which are obtained by using the eigenvectors of $P$ and $Q$. So my question is, does $\sigma(P-Q) \subset \{-1,0,1\}$ hold?
My intuition stems from the fact that if there exists an orthonormal basis $(e_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $P= \sum_{i \in I} |e_i \rangle \langle e_i|$ and $Q= \sum_{i \in J} |e_i \rangle \langle e_i|$, the spectrum must be restricted to $\{-1,0,1\}$.
When $P$ and $Q$ commute, we have for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ with eigenvector $\varphi$ of $P-Q$:
\begin{align}
\lambda^2 \varphi = (P-Q)^2 \varphi = \lambda \varphi + 2 (1 - P)Q\varphi
\end{align}
Thus, $\frac{1}{2}(\lambda^2-\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $(1-P)Q$, which is a projection. So $\frac{1}{2}(\lambda^2-\lambda) \in \{0,1\}$ and thus $\lambda \in \{-1,0,1\}$. However, the equation above does not hold if $P$ and $Q$ do not commute. Furthermore, this only restricts the eigenvalues to three discrete values, not the spectrum itself.
Is there an example of projections $P$ and $Q$ such that $\sigma(P-Q)$ is not contained in $\{-1,0,1\}$?

It's not difficult to come up with a counterexample. Try two orthogonal projections onto lines in $\Bbb{R}^2$, where the lines are not orthogonal (and distinct).

Hint to play with, for $t\in [0,1]$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P&=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix},
\\Q&=\begin{bmatrix}t&\sqrt{t(1-t)}\\ \sqrt{t(1-t)} & 1-t\end{bmatrix}.
\end{aligned}
$$
